# Help with this trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, elementary-functions

Here is the equation:

$$\sin^5(x) = \frac {\cos(x)}4$$

The answers should be between: 0° and 360°

I really tried and I dont even think it is possible to solve algebraically, maybe using numerical methods or other kind of black magic but that is very advanced for my grade. I am in high school.

Comment: Hint:
$$
\sin^5(x) = \frac {\cos(x)}4 \Leftrightarrow 4 = \cos x \csc^5 x
= \cot x \csc^4 x
$$
and you can change the $\csc x$'s to $\cot x$'s to get a quintic polynomial in $\cot x$ to solve.

Comment: @Malcolm This is alot to swallow as a hint. How do you know there is an effective solution to the quintic. Maybe if you workout the details and post as an answer.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yeah, I thought that too.  I saw the approach and posted the hint and am working on the details now.

Comment: One of my fears is that the problem is correctly stated. Maybe the poster could confirm this is the correct equation.

Comment: @Malcolm The quintic has an easily guessed solution.

Comment: Perhaps all that is desired is for you to spot a solution.  That is not difficult (just try the standard values for $x$).  No need to pass to the quintic.

Comment: Perhaps, since this is a high school class, the instructor expected the student to plug in a few of the special angles.

Comment: Yes, and one of the special angles works.

Comment: The quintic has one real root at $\cot x = 1$.  The other four roots are complex.

Comment: Yes, the problem is correctly stated. Also, the other problems could be solved algebraically so this one should be too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align} 
\sin^5x &= \frac{\cos x}4
,\\
(\sin^5x)^2 &= \left(\frac{\cos x}4\right)^2
,\\
\sin^{10}x &= \tfrac1{16}{\cos^2 x}
,\\
(\sin^{2}x)^5 &= \tfrac1{16}(1-\sin^2 x)
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
16(\sin^{2}x)^5+\sin^2 x-1&=0
,\\
(2\sin^2x-1)
(8\sin^8x+4\sin^6x+2\sin^4x+\sin^2x+1)
&=0
,\\
\cos2x\,(8\sin^8x+4\sin^6x+2\sin^4x+\sin^2x+1)
&=0.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
8\sin^8x+4\sin^6x+2\sin^4x+\sin^2x+1&>0\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\cos2x&=0
,\\
2x&=\tfrac\pi2+\pi k,\quad k=0,1,\dots
,\\
x&=\tfrac\pi4+\tfrac{\pi k}2,\quad k=0,1,\dots
.
\end{align}

For $x$ restricted to the interval $[0,2\pi]$,
we have four solutions
\begin{align} 
x_1&=\tfrac\pi4=45^\circ
,\\
x_2&=\tfrac\pi4+\tfrac\pi2=\tfrac{3\pi}4=135^\circ
.\\
x_3&=\tfrac\pi4+\pi=\tfrac{5\pi}4=225^\circ
.\\
x_4&=\tfrac\pi4+\tfrac{3\pi}2=\tfrac{7\pi}4=315^\circ
.\\
\end{align}

Substitution of $x_1,\dots,x_4$ into original equation
shows that only solutions $x_1,x_3$ are valid:

\begin{align} 
\sin^5x_1 &=\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\ 
\frac{\cos x_1}4&=\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\
\sin^5x_2 &=\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\ 
\frac{\cos x_2}4&=-\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\
\sin^5x_3 &=-\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\ 
\frac{\cos x_3}4&=-\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\
\sin^5x_4 &=-\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
,\\ 
\frac{\cos x_4}4&=\tfrac{\sqrt2}8
.
\end{align}

As @Malcolm noted, two extra solutions were
introduced by the squaring the original equation,
that's why the final check of the found roots is essential.

Comment: It seems to me that this key fact, the most important for the  for the solution was clearly pointed out in other answers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have a question, why is that a key fact? If a*b=0 then a=0 or b=0 and it shouldn't really matter if one is positive or negative.

Comment: You go from $\cos 2x = 0$ to $2x=\tfrac\pi2+2\pi k,\quad k=0,1,\dots$, but it should be $2x=\tfrac\pi2+\pi k,\quad k=0,1,\dots$ for the zeros of cosine.  You have gained extraneous solutions when you squared both sides of the the original equation, specifically while $x=3\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ are not solutions of the original equation, they are after squaring.

Comment: @Malcolm: thank you, you are absolutely right, fixed.

Comment: @SergioLoza: of course, 
$\dots>0$ just means that there are no real roots from this part.

Comment: @gimusi: this term is greater than 0,
since it's a sum of one and a sum of even powers of
$\sin x$ multiplied by positive coefficients,
and this means that this term $\ne0$ for real values of $x$.

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaanks

Comment: @g.kov ops...yes of course sorry I was really dumb to not see that!

Comment: ...also for this....:-)

Answer (score 7):

By letting $x=\arctan u$ the problem boils down to solving 
$$ (u-1)(4u^4+3u^3+3u^2+u+1)=0$$
and
$$ 4u^4+3u^3+3u^2+u+1 = \left(2u^2+\frac{3}{4}u\right)^2+\left(u+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{23}{16}u^2+\frac{3}{4}\geq \frac{3}{4} $$
is always positive, hence $u=1$ (i.e. $x\in\{\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}\}$) is the only solution.
*Completing the square* is a powerful technique: for instance, the decomposition
$$ 4u^4+3u^3+3u^2+u+1 = \left(2u^2+\frac{3}{4}u\right)^2+\frac{39}{16}\left(u+\frac{8}{39}\right)^2+\frac{35}{39} $$
proves that the LHS is $\geq\frac{35}{39}$: this is pretty close to the actual value of the minimum.

Comment: Brillant completing of the square! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it has solutions.

$$\sin^5(x) = \frac {\cos(x)}4 $$

$$4\sin^5(x) = \cos(x)$$

$$4\sin^4(x) \tan (x) =1$$

$$ 4(1-\cos ^2(x))^2 \tan (x) =1$$

$$4\tan x (\frac {\tan ^2x}{1+\tan ^2x})^2=1$$

$$4\tan ^5 x = ( 1+\tan ^2x)^2$$

Note that $$ \tan x =1 \implies x= \pi /4 \text { and } 5\pi/4 $$ are solutions.

Comment: Another solution is $x=5\pi/4$, and more generally $\pi/4 + n \pi$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ all work.

Comment: Oh, of course!  tanx=1 gives more solution thatn just  $\pi/4$

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of completeness I am posting this solution although I don't think that this is necessarily a high school approach.  The approach is based on the idea that equations with trigonometric functions are much more amenable to manipulation if there is only one trigonometric function involved.
$$
\sin^5(x) = \frac {\cos(x)}4 \\
4 = \cos x \csc^5 x\\
4= \cot x \csc^4 x \\
4 = \cot x (1+\cot^2 x)^2
$$
Or writing $u = \cot x$,
$$
u^5 + 2u^3 + u - 4 =0
$$
If we notice that $1+2+1 = 4$ it becomes easier to guess $u=1$ is a solution.  In terms of our original variable this is the solution $\cot x =1$ or $x = 45°$ 0r $225°$.

To see if there are any more solutions we could try to factor the other factor in the polynomial, $u^4+u^3+3u^2+3u+4$.  We would find that it has no real roots, but it is probably easier to consider the graphs of $y=\sin^5 x$ and of $y=\frac{\cos x}{4}$.  We can easily convince ourselves that there are only two intersections in $[0,360]$, so we have found all the solutions.